# Can't login to website using facebook's api's

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have some php code which worked nicely on my old server.  I have moved the php code to a new server, and now I can no longer use the facebook api's to log into my site using a facebook login.

Here is a screenshot of what happens on the new server:

[image]
Larger version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYSzZ.png).

I have checked apache's error.log file and I see no error messages.

Why would this be happening on a new server?

Comment: can you please tell which one was the reason for your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many reasons for this

- check that *domains* match in code and in settings
- check that *urls* match in code and in settings
- check that *login urls* for authentication match
- check that the *app secret* has not changed
- check that *sandbox mode* is off
- check for access of app from a developer account and not a testing account
- check if the url you are taking the user to, has all the required data.

Comment: As far as I know, if URL is different from the site url in settings its gives error mentioning `URL is not owned by the app` also, sandbox mode related error is `4oh4.php` if accessed from a non authorized account. this seems to be API or Secret key issue.

Comment: That error would only be shown to the developer of the apps, regular users see a generic error

Answer (score 1):

If it’s moving environments (i.e. from testing to live) then it’ll be your site URLs. Go to your app’s settings page at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and update your site URL in there.

Comment: Just done that now, and I am getting exactly the same error in the screenshot above.

Comment: I’d be able to diagnose better if you either didn’t remove the URL from the address bar, or pasted the URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have anything to do with apache, please add some parts of your code. Also are you sure about the canvas url and app ID setting with your new server?

Comment: `Also are you sure about the canvas url and app ID setting with your new server?`  This is probably what it is.  I will check asap.  Thanks.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this, I updated the url in the developer section of facebook, and I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Plus, I don't see how it can be a problem with the code when it works find on my old server, but not on my new server.  Both servers are using the same version of LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

go to apps >> your App >> edit app 
See if the url provided is correct

check if the appId and appSecret are correct

Answer (score 0):

check your site url at app setting while it contains proper server protocol like http:// or https://

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: now author find the solution.it is also the reason that may be mis configure the app setting while getting site url.