# Other users cant login using facebook's api on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm working with the PHP SDK on localhost. I've looked at other questions posted on here like this: 
[Can't login to website using facebook's api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413334/cant-login-to-website-using-facebooks-apis)

Domains, urls, login urls all match. The app secret and id match, sandbox was never turned on (double checked to make sure). I had trouble moving it to a new laptop, cuz the folder i put it in was called something else. After i changed that it worked fine.

The problem I'm having is, I as the owner of the app can log in and it does what i want it to do, but if i have a friend, or another user try to log in, it asks for permissions, then shows the "An error has occured, Please try later" facebook error page. Not entirely sure why its doing this, because i havn't hardcoded my info into it at all.

I've used different browsers, cleared cookies, nothing seems to work. Any ideas would be helpful.

EDIT: i've also tried destroying the session before login, didn't help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Other people cannot access your app 'on localhost' if they are not using your computer, which is the local host.

If you want other people to be able to use your app, they'll need a copy of your code, running on their local machine, or you'll need to make it available via a publicly accessible IP and/or domain name.

Comment: I meant they tried logging on from my computer, I made a new account and used that to log in, but it didn't work either. just took me to the error page. And I've gone through the code to make sure I havn't hardcoded anything in, destroyed session, different browsers. Would it have something to do with some setting being on/off allowing for only admins of the app to use it? (it just pulls data from fb and prints it out on a webpage)

Comment: Are you sure the app isn't in sandbox mode?

Comment: Nope, sandbox mode is turned off.

Comment: Weird...I decided to try just using the same settings on with a new app, all i did was replace the id and secret, turned on teh same settings on the new app and it worked. Not sure why it wasn't working with the first app..

Comment: Hi @Curiosus Mens. i was also trying to login using another username i just created but it does not login. shouldnt the user be allowed to login without creating any client id or secret? or using the same used used to create the app in fb