# publishing on facebook with sdk 3.0 and android doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I set a connection to fb in my app: clicking a button the app does the login, posts on the wall and then does logout. Everything works perfect for me with my developer account, but trying with other phones and other accounts, if official FB app is installed, the app doesn't publish anything. I have just changed  key-hash, i didn't use debug.keystore but a new keystore..... Anyone can help me????
Thank you very much!

i followed tutorials from fb, this is my login method

```
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    login=true;
    if (session!=null && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
            .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"))
            .setCallback(callback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, callback);
    }
}
```

this is all the "interesting" code

```
    boolean login= false;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void setEnt(Entry e) {
    art=e;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    login=true;
    if (session!=null && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
            .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"))
            .setCallback(callback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, callback);
    }
}   

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

     if (state.isOpened()) {
                publishStory();
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        }

}

private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(login){
    if (session != null){


        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", art.getTitle());
        postParams.putString("caption", art.getSection());
        postParams.putString("description", "xxx");
        postParams.putString("link", "xxx");
        postParams.putString("picture", "xxx");

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id")+"  articolo postato";

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                         .getApplicationContext(),
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                             .getApplicationContext(), 
                             postId,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        logout();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
        Log.v("FB", "FINE");
    }
    }
}

private void logout(){
    login=false;
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

    Session.setActiveSession(null);
}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


  }
```

Comment: Check the settings of your app in fb whether it is in sandbox mode. If it is then change it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your app may be placed in the sandbox mode and which is what causing others not from accessing your app. You may be the admin of the app and with your account you can access the app even in sandbox mode
[image: App settings page]

So disable it to make your app work for others.
Also check whether you have added the keyhash generated using your keystore file

Comment: What about the keyhash that you added? Was it generated using the keystore file instead of debug.keystore

Comment: yes!infact if i try to post even with official fb app installed, it works! I can't figure out why it does't works for everybody!:(

Comment: Once I had this issue and my app was automatically getting changd to sandbox mode even if I disable it. Can you please check if it is the same case with you. Also look for any developer alerts from facebook

Comment: just checked, sandbox is disabled!there aren't alerts .....thank you very much for trying helping me! if you want i'll post all codes!

Comment: I saw this from another post **Weird...I decided to try just using the same settings on with a new app, all i did was replace the id and secret, turned on teh same settings on the new app and it worked. Not sure why it wasn't working with the first app.** Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760994/other-users-cant-login-using-facebooks-api-on-localhost

Comment: mmmm ididn't understand, did he create a new application in facebook dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Turn-off the `sandbox mode` in your App settings.

Click here to go to your [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but like a said to mahesh, i had already disabled sandbox mode....